# Date Changed Event for JQueryMobile datepicker

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using the Datebox for JQueryMobile, but I can't find any way to hook in to the date changing event (probably missing something obvious!) I'm using the calendar inline so there is no text field available if that makes a difference.

Is there a way to trigger an event when I select a date in the calendar?
Thanks,
Becky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

This examples is made on a basis of a DateBox2, tell me if you are using older version.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ktbcP/15/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/<jqm-date></jqm-date>box.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
            <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true}'/>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $('#mydate').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
        if ( p.method === 'set' ) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
            alert('Changed');
        }
    });
});
```

## Explanation

DateBox2 has several callback functions and set is one of them. What you need to do is bind a datebox event to a input box, like this:

```
$('#mydate').bind('datebox', function(e, p) {
    if ( p.method === 'set' ) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        alert('Changed');
    }
});
```

And just check for an appropriate method. Their [**official documentation**](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/events.html) holds a full method list.

Unfortunately event that detects manual date change don't exist, if this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I needed - I was halfway there but this full example sorted out my problem :)

Comment: When you say "manual date change" - do you mean typing in the controls of the popup (which should trigger it), or using an unlocked input and changing it there (which I never considered having a trigger on - although I could add it if there is a need)